# Create Document in Elasticsearch Without Duplicate Parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to prevent duplicate entries into elasticsearch, but based on one of the parameters in the data. For example, if I have an object like below, I'd like to prevent another entry that has the same array of event_ids. Any ideas how to do this?

I'm coding this using the elasticsearch javascript API if it makes any difference.

```
{ start_date: '2015-11-19T08:46:14-05:00',
end_date: '2015-11-19T08:46:38-05:00',
length_seconds: 24,
number_events: 5,
event_ids: [ 5589253, 5589254, 5589255, 5589256, 5510380 ] },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a string with all the event ids concatenated, hash it, and then use that as the id of the document.
You should also sort and remove duplicates.

So for instance:
`sha1("5510380|5589253|5589254|5589255|5589256")`

That way a document with the same events will get the same `_id`. Then you can check whether that document exists or not.

Comment: Any ideas for something that uses less computational resources than a SHA hash?

Comment: Any hash would do, it is only used to shorten the string. For instance a fast one is [murmurhash3](https://github.com/karanlyons/murmurHash3.js). If the list isn't very long, then the raw string could also work.